# How to transform a property with a default value (also a DTO) using class-validator and class-transformer

Tags: typescript, class-validator, class-transformer

I am at my wits end and need to resort to asking a question because my research has not gotten me further. The `plainToClass` function is not transforming my default values.

Here some simple examples that will generate this issue.

My parent class:

```
export class NumberedSetDTO
{
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsArray()
  @IsNumber({}, { each: true })
  public reps: Array<number>;
}

export class ExerciseDto {
  @IsEnum(ExerciseName)
  public name!: ExerciseName;

  @IsArray()
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => NumberedSetDTO)
  public sets?: Array<NumberedSetDTO>;
}
```

Child class example. Here I set some defaults.

```
export class KSnatchDTO extends ExerciseDto {
  public name = ExerciseName.KSnatch;
  public sets= [{ reps: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10] }];
}
```

Transforming and validation. I want only those properties which have decorators to be validated and added to the transformed class.

```
    const workout = {
      name: 'k snatch',
    };
    const cls = plainToClass(KSnatchDTO, workout, {
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    });
```

The `sets` property is not of type `Array<NumberedSetDTO>` it just a plain object. So plainToClass is not transforming the nested properties properly.
e.g.

```
cls = KSnatchDTO{name:"k snatch", sets: Array(1)[Object]---> this should be  Array(1)[NumberedSetDTO]}
```

This is a problem because if I validate with whitelisting, the property `sets` will be removed because it's just a plain JS object.

On the other hand, here it will transform the `sets` property correctly

```
    const workout = {
      name: 'k snatch',
      sets: [{ reps: [10, 12] }],
    };
    const cls = plainToClass(KSnatchDTO, workout, {
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    });
```

Sets is of type `Àrray<NumberSetDTO>` and will not be removed after whitelisting.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try setting your enableImplicitConversion to false.

Comment: Yeah, the default is false anyway and I tried without that option as well.